# PyDev: Wrong autocompleted import path in same directory

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana, pydev, code-completion

I'm running PyDev 2.2.3 on Aptana 3.0

The following example project resembles my current working project:

```
  \project-dir
            \lib
            \main
```

In lib I have reader.py containing a base class Reader(object), and rssreader.py containing RSSReader(Reader).

I'd expect PyDev, when running the Fix/Order Imports to add a line to rssreader.py saying

```
from reader import Reader
```

instead it's autogenerating

```
from lib.reader import Reader
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related on how is configured your PYTHONPATH in your Pydev project.

If looks like your PYTHONPATH contains only **project-dir** so Pydev autoimport in an absolute way, so it makes `from lib.reader import Reader`.

If you want to have `from reader import Reader`, you'll have to put in your PYTHONPATH the **project-dir/lib directory** (in preference before the project-dir/ directory).

Comment: Is this desired behaviour, instead of looking at the relative path when 2 .py's are residing in the same directory?

Comment: @SjaakTrekhaak : it's often preferable to use absolute imports in python instead of relative one (in fact that's what PyDev choose). In python, you could use relative imports with `from .reader import Reader` (as explained by [PEP328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/))